# Which one is better, one 300GB EBS or three 100GB EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

When launching a new EC2 instance with EBS (especially the new C4 instance), which one is better? Assuming I need to provision 300 GB total.

1. 1 single 300 GB EBS storage to get 900 IOPS (General Purpose SSD) or
2. 3 EBS storage with 100 GB each and get 300 IOPS (General Purpose SSD) only for each storage?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will give you faster performance and better reliability. With 3 EBS volumes you need to stripe them to make a single one and a failure on any of the three will result in a complete failure of all.

Comment: With 3 storage, I can mount it as xvda, xvdb, xvdc. If one disk fails or corrupt, at least the others 2 are not. With one single storage, if the disk fails or corrupt, I might lose all the data.

Comment: ok, I thought you wanted to present a single filesystem of 300GBs, and you wanted to stripe the 3 EBS volumes at the EC2 level.